# c# iTextSharp Combine two 'Chunk'

Tags: c#, itext, phrase

I need to know if its possible to combine two `Chunk` from `iTextSharp`

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
var text1 = new Chunk("hello");
var text2 = new Chunk("world");

phrase.add();
```

I want to combine `text1` and `text2`, and then add them to a `phrase`.

Answer (score 6):

**FIXED**

I already fixed it doing this

```
var text1 = new Chunk("hello");
var text2 = new Chunk("world");
var phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.Add(text1);
phrase.Add(text2);
```